# Trying to vertically center with Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm creating a simple footer and want all of the text in it to be vertically centered.  I tried several things but none of this worked:

```
footer {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: lightgray;
    flex: display;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    color: blue;
}
```

The horizontal centering works great.  What am I doing wrong with the vertical centering?

Answer (score -1):

You have `flex: display;` it should be `display: flex;`

When you make this adjustment, you will see it works to your request.